# CPLEX Error 1016: Promotional version , use academic version CPLEX

Tags: python, cplex

I am using python with clpex, when I finished my model I run the program and it throws me the following error:

CplexSolverError: CPLEX Error 1016: Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded.

I have the IBM Academic CPLEX installed, how can I make python recognize this and not the promotional version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to the direction you install CPLEX. For Example, D:\Cplex
After that you will see a foler name cplex, then you click on that, --> python --> choose the version of your python ( Ex: 3.6 ), then choose the folder x64_win64, you will see another file name cplex. 
You copy this file into your python site packakges ^^ and then you will not be restricted

Answer (score 1):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html

> Setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH
>
> If you run multiple versions of CPLEX side-by-side, then use this way
>   of declaring the location of CPLEX and its Python API to your Python
>   installation by means of the environment variable PYTHONPATH.
>
> To start using the CPLEX Python API, set the Python path environment
>   variable PYTHONPATH to the value of
>   yourCplexhome/python/VERSION/PLATFORM. Setting this environment
>   variable enables that version of Python to find the CPLEX modules that
>   it needs to run Python commands and scripts that use the CPLEX Python
>   API.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer, you can use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Another alternative is to install the academic version of the `cplex` package *over the top* of the free "community edition". This would work for you system Python or for a virtualenv. For example, you can do something like the following:

```
$ cd <COSDIR>/cplex/python/2.7/<platform>/
$ pip install .
Processing /home/rkersh/opt/CPLEX_Studio128/cplex/python/2.7/x86-64_linux
Building wheels for collected packages: cplex
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cplex ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/rkersh/.cache/pip/wheels/88/19/c6/6545d3d5ac65b18b796b44986272e17f3a8429df7b12472624
Successfully built cplex
Installing collected packages: cplex
  Found existing installation: cplex 12.8.0.1
    Uninstalling cplex-12.8.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled cplex-12.8.0.1
Successfully installed cplex-12.8.0.0
```

For the first command, `COSDIR` is the location you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio and `platform` is something like `x86-64_linux`, `x64_win64`, `x86-64_osx`, etc. In the example above, you can see that `COSDIR` was `/home/rkersh/opt/CPLEX_Studio128` and `platform` was `x86-64_linux`. After doing this, you should not get [CPXERR_RESTRICTED_VERSION](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/macros/CPXERR_RESTRICTED_VERSION.html) any more.